# Creating uicollectionview layout 3x3 and horizontal paging

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView and I want to make it to show at most 9 images on the screen at a time... 3x3 and I want to load 9 at a time by scrolling from the right to the left (and being able to see the ones already loaded, without reloading be scrolling from left to right).

I've been doing some research and I don't think I know how to even ask the correct question.

Does anyone have any idea where I can start to look?

Thanks.

Comment: thanks... sorry... uicollectionview

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://mobileappdev.learningtree.com/2012/12/13/paging-with-collection-views-part-1/) is a good place to start.